# SQL - How To Group Data Following Individual Row Calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I'm fascinated by this problem. Here's a stripped down version of my full sqlite query:

```
SELECT OrderID,
       UnitPrice,
       Quantity,
       Discount
FROM Order Details;
```

Which returns this:

```
OrderID  UnitPrice  Quantity  Discount
10248    14.0       12        0.00
10248    9.8        10        0.00
10248    34.8        5        0.00
10249    18.6        9        0.00
10249    42.4       40        0.00
10250    7.7        10        0.00
10250    42.4       35        0.15
10250    16.8       15        0.15
10251    16.8       6         0.05
10251    15.6       15        0.05
```

I want to return a new column called `total price`. This would be a calculation of `UnitPrice` multiplied by `Quantity` less the corresponding percentage `Discount`. The complication arises however in that the new column should be grouped by the `OrderID` to represent the total order price less the individual % discounts.

I've been chasing my tail with `SUM` aggregates and `GROUP BY`'s for hours. Summing the UnitPrices and Quantities is fine, but as the discount applies to different values it's almost like the discount needs to be calculated first. The discount does not need to apply individually to each item btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming you use MySQL. Slight variation may be needed for MS SQL server but the idea is the same for both.

For sake of understanding this better, split this into two stages.

First count the line item price:

```
SELECT OrderID,
       UnitPrice,
       Quantity,
       Discount,
       UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount) total
      FROM OrderDetails;
```

And then apply `GROUP BY` with `SUM()`, so your final query would be:

```
SELECT OrderID,
       SUM(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount)) total
      FROM OrderDetails
      GROUP BY OrderID;
```

Comment: this is good but I'm ideally looking for a way to do this in one query if possible. I've updated the question to give you a better sense of why I'd like to avoid two queries.

Comment: First one is just a sample, you can just use the second query

Comment: I follow. My bad. The second example works perfectly when adapted into my full query.